# AVPlayerLayer inside UITableViewCell reload issue

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I've got custom UITableViewCell class which keeps AVPlayerLayer inside one of its view (called videoView). Everytime I have to load a new cell (inside *cellForRow...* method) I'm checking if there's AVPlayerLayer and creating new one in case it wasn't made in the past:

```
    _playerLayer = nil ;
    for(CALayer * layer in _videoView.layer.sublayers)
        if ([layer isKindOfClass:[AVPlayerLayer class]]) {
            _playerLayer = (AVPlayerLayer*) layer;
        }

    if(!_playerLayer)
    {
        _playerLayer.player = nil ; 
        _playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer layer];
        [_videoView.layer addSublayer:_playerLayer];
    }
```

Sometimes, I want to reload whole cell while video is playing (for example in order to update height or subtitle). *cellForRow...* method is called again, but that time I am getting new cell (is there way to force using old cell instead of getting new instance?). I want to move state of player/player layer from one view to another. I am doing it that way:

```
      // create AVPlayerLayer
      if(iAmPlayingButCellIsReloaded)
        {
            _playerLayer.player = playerWhichIsPlaying;
            // time resets to 0 here
        }
```

Mostly, it's working correctly, but there are cases when video restarts (moving to the beginning) after replacing cells. It happens every first reload and rarely during next iterations. 
Is there fix for that? Should I wait to finish video, and then reload cell? Can I somehow force to use old cell while reloading row? Is there better way to copy AVPlayerLayer/AVPlayer from one place to another?